# добавление в массив массива, с последующим его удалением

Tags: javascript

Есть массив на 400 элементов, я хочу их отсортировать чтобы элементы в массиве были по 4. к примеру `[[1,2,3,4], [a,b,c,d], [true,false,true,false]]` и тд..

пытался реализовать таким образом:

```
var arr = [....]// не сортированный массив.

var main = [];
var secondary = [];
for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
 secondary.push(arr[i]);
  if(secondary.length === 4){
   main.push(secondary);
   secondary.length = 0; // очищаю чтобы наполнить по новой
  }
 }
```

Но при очищении `secondary` массива очищается он и в `main`.. (странно ведь если пушить просто элементы, а после "чистить" переменную, то в main элемент не удаляется, в отличии от массива)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае сохраняется ссылка на массив `secondary`, поэтому когда меняется этот объект, например с помощью присваивания `length`, то все ссылки указывают на новое измененное значение.

Для решения, нужно просто присваивать новый массив

```
secondary = [];
```

вместо

```
secondary.length = 0;
```

Comment: работает как часы! спасибо. Выходит когда мы пушим не массив, а одиночные элементы то они пушатся не как ссылки? (к примеру `var x = []; var y = 123; x.push(y); y.length = 0;` х все равно сохранит в себе 123)

Comment: @Jonny, это все потому, что у `y`, так как это число, нет свойства `length` и таким способом _y.length = 0_ происходит попытка добавить это свойство, и если вызывать это в strict режиме будет ошибка _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'length' on number_ а без строгого режима присваивание просто проигнорируется. Таким образом переменная не изменилась, следовательно и значение в массиве тоже не должно было поменяться, значит все работает как и ожидалось.

Comment: понял, спасибо за разьяснение!